# Getting Random Object from array which satisfies condition

Tags: java

Say I have two arrays
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[true, false, true, false, false true];

I want to get a random number from the first list but only if the number corresponds to a true value in the array. Is there an fast, memory efficient way of doing this which - for my specific case - dosen't use Java.util.Arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IntStream.filter to get only the values that are true and get a random value from that array. This is vastly more efficient if you need to obtain multiple random numbers.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
boolean[] good = {true, false, true, false, false true};
int[] choices = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).filter(i->good[i]).map(i->arr[i]).toArray();
int randVal = choices[(int)(Math.random()*choices.length)];
```

Comment: this is good however, Im trying to only get a single number once

Comment: @Bykaugan I do not understand your comment? How does this Answer not solve your Question?

Comment: @hev1 Isn't the complexity of this answer O(n), with n being arr.length ?

Comment: @EEAH Yes, it is. Why?

Comment: @hev1 Just wondering if there is another solution that has lower complexity, since this one will always loop n times (O(n) in the worst and best case). One may be choosing a random index `k` and checking if `good[k] == true` with keeping track of the already checked indexes (still have linear time complexity O(n) in the worst case but O(1) in the best case).

Comment: @EEAH Actually, it only needs to loop `n` times **once**. After that, getting a random number should be a constant time operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool random_condition = false ;
int random_index;
do {
    Random random = new Random () ;
    random_index = random().nextInt(7);
    random_condition = condition_array [random_index]
while (random_condition = false);
```

With `condition_array = [true, false, true, false, false true]`

Comment: this might take infinite amount of time. Im looking for a solution which is relativly quick

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public static int getRandomInt() {
    int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    boolean[] boolArray = {true, false, true, false, false, true};
    Vector<Integer> choices = new Vector<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < boolArray.length; i++) {
        if (boolArray[i]) {
            choices.add(intArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return choices.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, choices.size()));
}
```

This is a linear solution that avoids `java.util.ArrayList`.
That said, there are better ways to implement this without using two separate arrays, so  I'd suggest reevaluating your design.